# How well does Plastic SCM import from SourceSafe?

Tags: migration, visual-sourcesafe, plasticscm

I'm evaluating SCM's for a potential move away from SourceSafe. Plastic SCM makes a good impression. I saw that it has an importer from SourceSafe but couldn't find a lot of information about how it handles some of VSS specialities - namely "Shared files". Anyone have experience with that particular aspect or this migration in general?

Answer (score 2):

Once you move away from VSS you'll find that the "shared files" concept doesn't exist "as is" in other systems.

That being said, I bet you need to "upgrade" to a "component based development" model, which is a cool name to describe what you're looking for.

There are two interesting links you should read:

- Component Oriented Development: http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/component-based-development.aspx
- Migration guide from VSS to Plastic SCM: http://www.plasticscm.com/releases/3.0.1/migration-guides/vss_migration.pdf

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for those links, That first one was new to me and cleared up a few things. I am more than happy to move away from shared files and use a component based approach. The question is can the migration tool do that conversion or will it simply separate shared files into individual entities?